# How to delete the multiplies files in S3 by using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to delete the multiple files in AWS.

Getting the files data from my database, calling a `get()` function and wrote a loop condition, in the loop getting the file name and deleting the files based on that file name in S3.

But in my code not throwing any error and also not deleting the files in my S3 Account, here is code.

```
   def post(self, request):
        try:
            log_request(request)
            company_id = request.data.get('ip_company_id')
            execute_function = query_executer(company_id)
            user_id = request.data.get('ip_user_id')
            use_date =  datetime.now().date() - timedelta(days = 5)
            s3_resource = boto3.client("s3",aws_access_key_id=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_AccessKeyId,
                              aws_secret_access_key=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_SecretAccessKey)
            bucket_name = settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_NAME
            params = {

                'ip_company_id': company_id,
                'ip_user_id':user_id
            }
                        for object in result :
                for files in object['files']:
                  filename = object['files']['file_name']
                  folder_id = object['files']['folder_id']
                  folder_name = object['files']['folder_name']
                  # folders_id = object['folders'][0]['folder_id']
                # folders_name = object['folders'][0]['folder_name']


                if folder_id == 0:
                    response = s3_resource.delete_object(Bucket=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_NAME, Key=(str(company_id)+'/'+filename ) )
                    # deletefilesandfolders(user_id,company_id)
                if folder_id > 0 :
                    response = s3_resource.delete_object(Bucket=settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_NAME,Key=(str(company_id) + '/'+folder_name+'/'+ filename))
```

Comment: If you are wanting to delete **multiple** objects, then the line containing `delete_object()` should be indented _within_ the `for` loop. At the moment, it would only be deleting the _last_ object because the delete command is running _after_ the `for` loop. If things still aren't working after that is fixed, I suggest adding `print('Deleting:',settings.S3_BUCKET_BUCKET_NAME,filename)` before the `delete_object()` to see what it is attempting to delete. Alternatively, call `delete_objects()` (plural), which accepts a list of objects in one API call.

Comment: no luck @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Are your `print()` statements showing the correct Bucket and Key? What is the contents of the `response` that comes back each time?

Comment: yes @JohnRotenstein i am trying to loop the files and trying to delete the files but the loop getting only 1 file not all files are looping

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect. The `if folder_id` statements should be indented an additional level to be _inside_ the `for files` loop. Once again, I recommend that you use `print()` statements to help you debug what is happening.